# How is interval used when submitting a rate custom metric to Datadog

Tags: datadog

How is the interval parameter used by Datadog when sending custom metrics? What happens if you send overlapping intervals of rate samples to the Datadog custom metrics API? https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/custom_metrics/#custom-metrics-properties.

Ie. if we sample the per second rate of a thing every 15 minutes by taking into account how many times it happened in the last 30 min. You can provide the interval in to Datadog API (which would be 30 mins in this case), how does Datadog use that? And how does it reconcile it with getting a value for the metric every 15 minutes?